# Encoding multimedia file formats programmatically

Tags: php, encoding, binary

I'm always wondered where to find rules to encode known file formats, for example: .jpg, .png, .mpg programmatically. How to write these binary formats? Some years ago, when I surfed phpBB scripts, I found that they for example don't use any gd or imagemagick, they write it in binary way. Not only for php, but for other languages as well?

Comment: Internet is the source of such a knowledge. Just try google for "png file format". You'll be surprized

Answer (score 1):

- The [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) seems to have a pretty good rundown on the PNG format's internal structure
- The [JPEG standard](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf) (PDF) - read the [Wikipedia article on JPG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) as an introduction
- Here's a nice one for GIF: [GIF spec](http://www.daubnet.com/en/file-format-gif) and the official one (much more heavy reading): [Gif89a](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt)

Video encoding is a whole different issue, and orders of magnitude more complex... Although I imagine one can already spend a *lot* of time understanding the JPEG format in depth.

Usually, looking up the desired format's article in Wikipedia will either give you the format definition, or a link to the specification.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the "data:" URI specification? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,AAAA" alt="blank">
```

Simply [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encode your image, set the correct mime type, and have fun.

Note that this defeats browser caching of images, and base64-encoding leads to roughly 4/3 size increase of the data transfer required. So it's not an obvious performance win.